# Software scaling for parallel processing

Tags: parallel-processing, parallels

I have a question about software scaling.
Is there any kind of programming language to program parallel processing algorithms with software scaling Or is software scaling a kind of algorithm and can be programmed with any kind of languages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling meaning the ability of your system to be expanded (increase number of processing units) at a large scale to accommodate the increase in the data size.

> **Scalability** is the ability of a system, network, or process to handle a growing amount of work in a capable manner or its ability to be enlarged to accommodate that growth. For example, it can refer to the capability of a system to increase its total output under an increased load when resources (typically hardware) are added. An analogous meaning is implied when the word is used in an economic context, where scalability of a company implies that the underlying business model offers the potential for economic growth within the company.

Parallel Programming on the other hand is writing code of your algorithm in away able to run in multi-processing system or machine, to take advantage of the n processing elements that are withen the systems.

There are many parallel programming frameworks written in different programming languages: for example there is CUDA written by NVIDIA in C/C++, and OpenCL in both C/C++ and python , MPI ,OpenMP , Intel Thread Block and Intel Cilk. each has its advantage and usage over the other.

This is the best source to learn all about parallel world: check this online course
https://open.hpi.de/courses/parprog2014